# How can i add extra field on this select2 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am trying to get more field filled with a select2 drop-down menu.
Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ws3tjp5f/

I want the `"Select extra"` to be populated too.
But with a different value.

Now I can print id & text, I want to store and print one more value `"extra"`

***html:***

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" />
<p>Selected IDs: <input type="text" id="selectedID"/></p>
<p>Selected Options: <input typ="text" id="selectedText"/></p>
<p>Selected Extra Field: <input typ="text" id="selectedExtra"/></p>
```

**js:**

```
var test = $('#test');
$(test).select2({
placeholder: "Choose",
data:[
    {id:0,text:"enhancement"},
    {id:1,text:"bug"},
    {id:2,text:"duplicate"},
    {id:3,text:"invalid"},
    {id:4,text:"wontfix"}
],
width: "300px"
});

$(test).change(function() {

var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
var theExtra = $(test).select2('data').text;
$('#selectedID').val(theID);
$('#selectedText').val(theSelection);
$('$selectedExtra').val(theExtra);
});
```

Comment: Im using php and JSON in my actual code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws3tjp5f/2/) for this, you also have a typo on $('$selectedextra'), it should be         $('#selectedextra'), basically i just added a new column on the JSON data called 'extra'.

```
    var test = $('#test');
    $(test).select2({
        placeholder: "Choose",
        data:[
            {id:0,text:"enhancement",extra:"one"},
            {id:1,text:"bug",extra:"two"},
            {id:2,text:"duplicate",extra:"three"},
            {id:3,text:"invalid",extra:"four"},
            {id:4,text:"wontfix",extra:"five"}
        ],
        width: "300px"
    });

    $(test).change(function() {

        var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
        var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
        var theExtra = $(test).select2('data').extra;

        $('#selectedID').val(theID);
        $('#selectedText').val(theSelection);
        $('#selectedExtra').val(theExtra);

    });
```

Comment: How should the php line look like?    $answer[] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"text"=>$row['text'],"extra"=>$row['extra']);

Answer (score -1):

```
var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
var theExtra = $(test).select2('data').text;
$('#selectedID').val(theID);
$('#selectedText').val(theSelection);
-->    $('#selectedExtra').val(theExtra);
});
```

this line

```
$('#selectedExtra').val(theExtra);
```

Comment: I dont understand! What todo with that line? and how do i add data to "selectExtra"?